# In below steps, How can you go from 1st step to 2nd? What operations are done here?

Tags: integration, logarithms

How did the book go from
$$
\int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}
$$
to
$$
\log\left( v + \sqrt{v^2 + 1} \right) \;?
$$

EDIT-
I know integration and I came up with the formula something like this after integration

$$
2(1+v^2)^{1/2}(v+{v^3/3})
$$

but as I am solving a homogeneous differential equation, the other side of equation is log cx after integration and I need this side in log too. So the book came to the 2nd step shown above. I can't get my head around how they came up with a log in the equation.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts, don't post photos as some users may not be able to see them, and they are not searchable

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. What do you know about integration? What have you tried? Is there anything earlier in the book that helps explain this?

Comment: Take the derivative of the second expression. Does it give the integrand?

Comment: I've edited the question, please take a look @EthanBolker

Comment: I think this is a standard trigonometric substitution - try $v = \tan \theta$. That's how the author "came up with the solution". You can of course check it by differentiating. See @TheDeadLegend 's correct answer.

Comment: You did not show how you got $2(1+v^2)^{1/2}(v+{v^3/3}),$ but it is not the integral of $1/\sqrt{1+v^2}.$ There is an error in your calculations.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for pointing that out, as I have mentioned on other comment, I am weak at this.

Comment: Your own result regarding this integral seems to be a result of something like a chain rule for integration: the integral of $1/\sqrt{x}$ is $2\sqrt{x}$ and hence for $1/\sqrt{1 + v^{2}}$ you get $2\sqrt{1 + v^{2}}$ and multiply it by integral of $(1  + v^{2})$. Unfortunately integration is hard/tricky and it does not have simple rules corresponding to those of derivatives (like product/quotient/chain rule).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yeah exactly, I've used chain rule.

Comment: Unfortunately the "chain rule for integration" is a false technique that gives wrong answers. There are very few direct methods you can apply to integrals the way you can apply the chain rule or product rule to derivatives; that is why first year calculus tortures you by asking you to memorize many specialized solution methods to apply in various circumstances. Most students who study calculus spend at least a semester being drilled in these things (and probably forgetting most of them soon after).

Comment: @DavidK Thank you. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v$=$\tan\theta$
$$\int\frac{\sec^2\theta.d\theta}{\sec\theta}\tag{1}$$
$$\int \sec\theta$$
$$\int\frac{\sec\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta).d\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}\tag{2}$$
$$\int\frac{\sec^2\theta+\sec\theta.\tan\theta.d\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}$$
Since numerator is the derivative of denominator 
$$\int\frac{du}{u}\tag{situation is like this}$$
$$\ln u\tag{3}$$
$$\ln (\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$$
$$\ln(v+\sqrt{1+v^2})$$

Edit:

See, It's usually achieved via trigo substitution.

In step $(1)$, I took $d(\tan\theta)=\sec^2\theta .d\theta$ 
In step $(2)$ , i multiplied and divided by $\sec\theta+\tan\theta$

Now since $d(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)=\sec^2\theta+\sec\theta.\tan\theta$ $d\theta$, I took it as a case I mentioned of $\ln u$. Any other problem in this solution?

Comment: Sorry to say but my mathematics is kind of weak so I am having difficulties understanding what you did. Also, is there any other way to achieve this? Because as per the context of this problem in this book, there should not be any trig functions invloved.

Comment: @SamvidMistry I will edit to explain it better, and i guess that this ws the easiest method.

Comment: @SamvidMistry Why should there not be any trig functions involved? If you have to solve an integral, you choose a method that works, unless the intent of the exercise is to learn a different integration method (in which case the book should explicity _tell_ you which methods you may or may no use).

Comment: @DavidK I just feel that because throughout this chapter of differential equations, they have not used neither mentioned about using any trig functions. I know this book is really bad in terms of explanation, but unfortunately I have to use only this for the exams.

Comment: The part where you multiply and divide by $(\sec\theta + \tan\theta)$ is non-obvious unless you have seen this somewhere. The substitution via hyperbolic functions (see other answer) is more natural provided one knows about these functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've asked this question during introduction to integrals. That's why I remember this method

Comment: @SamvidMistry Don't assume that the author of a book assumes you are ignorant of some fact or technique just because a particular chapter has not yet mentioned it. I would suspect the author assumes you have already seen the fact that $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}=\log\left( v + \sqrt{v^2 + 1} \right)+C,$ unless they showed some intermediate steps that you have not told us about.

Comment: @DavidK there are no intermediate steps. And yeah, the author assumes so many of these kind of facts and techniques are known by us and have used freely throughout the book. Do you have any resource which has a collection or examples of these kind of "facts and techniques"?

Comment: @SamvidMistry: I think if you are solving differential equations then these kind of results will already be available in chapters related to integration (formulas for integration of trig functions, algebraic functions etc). The particular integral in question is a standard one and should be part of memory of students who have learnt integration. Maybe you can revisit chapters on integration and find this formula.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yeah there should be but this book isn't about teaching integrations, it is about advanced maths, it has differential equations and Laplace etc., so unfortunately there isn't. It will be really helpful if you can point me to some resource for formulas like this.

Comment: @SamvidMistry: I think you should read some integration chapters from any textbook of calculus. These integral formulas should be there in any book on calculus.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Thank you so much. I got the whole solution except one part, where did the $$sec \theta$$ in the denominator in step 1 come from?

Comment: @SamvidMistry using $\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}=\sec\theta$

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Awesome, saved me from failing the exam.

Comment: @SamvidMistry Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Let's cheat a little.

$$(\log(v+\sqrt{v^2+1}))'=\frac{(v+\sqrt{v^2+1})'}{v+\sqrt{v^2+1}}=\frac{1+\dfrac v{\sqrt{v^2+1}}}{v+\sqrt{v^2+1}}=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{v^2+1}}\frac{v+\sqrt{v^2+1}}{v+\sqrt{v^2+1}}.$$

---

Without cheating, you can use the change of variable $u=\sinh t$, which implies $\sqrt{v^2+1}=\cosh t$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on u = sinh t? and how can I achieve the answer using this change of variable?

Comment: @SamvidMistry: well, it seems that you haven't learnt about the changes of variable yet, so better wait until then.

Comment: I know about the change of variable. It is where you assume u = something and differentiate both sides to change the differential and limits, if present, in equation and reduce complexity. But I can't get this piece, why does the 1st statement u = sinh t imply the other one.

Comment: What do you get by performing the subsitution ?

Comment: I think the $u$ was meant to be $v.$ I know the technique is often called "U substitution", but that doesn't mean that it's literally "$u=$" every time someone uses the technique. In this case it might be clearer to say we set $t=\sinh^{-1} v,$ therefore $v=\sinh t$ and $\sqrt{1+v^2} = \cosh t.$

Comment: if I differentiate both sides, we get $$\frac{du}{dt} = cosh (t)$$ then, why is $$cosh(t) = \sqrt(v^2+1)$$, is that a formula? and if I replace cosh with $$\sqrt(v^2+1)$$, I will end up with $$\frac{du}{dt} = \sqrt(v^2+1)$$, in this both sides have no connection to each other, so if I substitute it in the original equation, it will just introduce another variable t. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: @SamvidMistry: if you haven't heard of the hyperbolic functions, then use the substitution by TheDeadLegend.

Comment: I know about hyperbolic functions, I was hoping I learn things more concretely rather than just applying a formula so it would be good if you can explain it by showing actual substitution in problem. it's okay if you can't. Thank you.

Comment: @SamvidMistry: if you know everything, then there is no obstacle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I understand sir why you feel there is no obstacle, but I am still not getting how you got from $$u = sinh(t)$$ to $$\sqrt(v^2+1) = cosh(t)$$ and how do I substitute it in the actual problem to get a logarithmic answer. I am clearly asking for steps. If you can really show me the steps to get to the answer I want, it would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @SamvidMistry: review the properties of the hyperbolic functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Answer (score 1):

The correspondence between

$$(a) \ \ \ln\left( v + \sqrt{v^2 + 1} \right) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \  \ \ (b) \ \ \int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}$$

can be made rather evident is one considers the change of variable $v=\sinh(t)$,

giving (remember that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$):

$$(a) \ \ \ln\left(\sinh(t) + \cosh(t) \right) \ \ \ \  \text{and} \ \  \ \ (b) \ \ \int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\sinh(t)}{\cosh(t)}$$

i.e. (note that $\mathrm{d}\sinh(t)=\cosh(t)\mathrm{d}t$):

$$(a)  \ \ln(e^t)  \  \ \  \text{and} \ \  \ \ (b) \ \ \int 1 dt $$

I leave the conclusion to you.

Comment: Damn! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Sorry I can't upvote you because of low reputation.

Comment: Well, I upvote.

Comment: @Takahiro Waki Thanks!